# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for joda-time in android

Tags: android, jodatime

I have a problem with `joda-time` and its integration to my Android app.

I want to deserialize JSON which contains a DateTime object which is represented with a string:

```
{
     "userId": 333,
     "username": "myuserid",
     "timestamp": "2014-11-19T17:02:11.454Z"
}
```

But unfortunatelly I receive a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/convert/ToString...     
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.convert.ToSt
```

I tried to add `joda-converter` and to add `joda-time` dependency with the same version as server has. But inspite of this I constantly receive the exception. My current `joda-time` dependecies are:

```
compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.8.1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
```

I also tried to user `joda-time-android` but it also was not successful.

Comment: clean you project and rerun again please.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the `org.joda.convert` I found out, that `org.joda.convert.ToString` is an interface. You cannot use it to convert.
Assuming that you successfully parsed JSON `String` and your object's definition is:

```
public class json {
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String timestamp;
}
```

And here is the question what would you like to do, because you haven't precised exactly.
If you would like to convert `String` `timespamp` to `DateTime` object from [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) library, follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date). It provides solution to parse it, as the date you provided is a standard ISO-8601 date describing format.

However importing whole library just to parse a `String` to `Date` is an inefficient solution. [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) suffers from slow initialisation and the performace matters on Android. Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217193/6507689) to convert String to `Java`'s `Date` object without importing a library, which has 4755 methods.